# Does male ejaculation shortens life span?

Tags: sex, research, penis, life-expectancy, ejaculation

I read many articles about this. I even talked to my doctor and other people. But it looks like everybody has an opinion, but nobody actually really knows if it's true.

Let's take 25 year old male.  How often can he ejaculate? In general  does each additional ejaculation takes a toll  on a life span?

Dear experts please clarify this

Comment: Hi! Could you link to the _many articles_ that relate to male ejaculation and its impact on life span? If you want us to clarify this, it would be useful to link to those articles, in order to help us providing an accurate answer. Thanks for editing your question. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Answer (score 2):

If a male person ejaculates the body produces certain hormones, such as dopamine, which is a happiness hormone. It is the reason for the good feeling - your body relaxes. Your well being increases, your organs work well. To make it short: Ejaculation, no matter how often, does not make your life shorter and it does not make your life longer. It just increases your well being. It can only be dangerous if you forget to eat or drink or something like that because you are 'too busy ejaculating'. In that case you would need professional help. What did your doctor say about your question? I am very interested in that, because a doctor should know it isn't bad for your life or anything.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Health SE. This is an interesting answer. Thank you. Would you mind just adding some references to support your claims (in accordance with Health SE policies http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers)? Thank you. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith